# Deleted (seemingly essential) startup application

Tags: luna

I accidentally deleted a startup application in Luna which leaves me with a blank desktop without Plank or Slingshot at startup...

It must have been from the top of the list which is in alphabetical order, if that helps.

Any clues which one that could have been and how to get it back?

Comment: How did you remove it? maybe you removed some important dependencies and not just one application.

Answer (score 4):

You've most likely removed `cerbere` which is the process that starts (and watches) desktop components like the panel, dock, and applications menu.

1. Open Terminal with <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and run `gnome-session-properties`
2. Add `cerbere`